# Strange behavior of Power BI line and column chart

Tags: powerbi

I have a simple data sheet containing 3 data rows.

[image]

The Power BI "Line and clustered column chart" show it like this:

[image]

But once I changed the row 2 data to below:
[image]

The visual suddenly changed to this.
[image]

The bar is showing correctly `0.98`. But the line drops to `0`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

According to here: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Clustered-amp-Line-Column-Chart-Line-value-does-not-align-with/m-p/479701

I need to set the start and end value for the Y-axis line as well...

[image]